# MYSQL - TRIGGER combined with IF + INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, sql-insert

everyone

My code doesn't have primary key nor foreign key on purpose so I'm looking for a solution without adding that.
My error is:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cedula' in 'field list'

The trigger is the problem because when I drop the trigger it works well so I don't know how to create the trigger. What I want with the trigger is to have in a table called *audit1* the duplicate data that is INSERT INTO *personas table* so I can tell which ID is twice or more in the table personas.

Hope you can help me. I write my all code down here.

```
CREATE DATABASE auditoria;
USE auditoria;

CREATE TABLE personas
(
    cedula BIGINT,
    nombre VARCHAR(30),
    codciudadnacimiento INT,
    codactividadlaboral INT
);

CREATE TABLE ciudadesnacimiento
(
    codciudadnacimiento INT,
    nombreciudadnacimiento  VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE actividadeslaborales
(
    codactividadlaboral INT,
    nombreactividadlaboral VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE audit1
(
    cedula BIGINT,
    nombre VARCHAR(30),
    observacion VARCHAR(30),
    fecha DATETIME
);

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER SPT1
AFTER INSERT ON personas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (cedula = NEW.cedula)
    THEN 
    INSERT INTO audit1  VALUES
    (NEW.cedula, NEW.nombre, 'DUPLICATE ID', NOW());
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO ciudadesnacimiento VALUES
(1, 'Bogota'),
(3, 'Cartagena');

INSERT INTO actividadeslaborales VALUES
(1, 'Medico'),
(2, 'Abogado');

INSERT INTO personas VALUES
(100,'Megadeth', 1, 1),
(100,'Megadeth', 1, 1),
(100,'Megadeth', 1, 1),
(200,'Babasonicos', 2, 2),
(200,'Babasonicos', 2, 2),
(200,'Babasonicos', 2, 2),
(300,'Spinetta', 3, 3),
(400,'Paez', 3, 3),
(500,'Charly', 3, 3),
(500,'Charly', 3, 3);
```

I want to be able to insert data into personas table without that mistake.

Comment: IF (cedula = , where should cedula come from? It’s not a variable nor input.

Comment: *`IF (cedula = NEW.cedula)`* What `cedula` do you mean??

Comment: *What I want with the trigger is to have in a table called audit1 the duplicate data that is INSERT INTO personas table so I can tell which ID is twice or more in the table personas.* Use IF EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need in

```
CREATE TRIGGER SPT1
BEFORE INSERT ON personas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM personas WHERE cedula = NEW.cedula)
    THEN 
        INSERT INTO audit1  VALUES
        (NEW.cedula, NEW.nombre, 'DUPLICATE ID', NOW());
    END IF;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/94TG_YmB